# How does android connect to vpn?

Tags: android, vpn

Im trying to understand how does google connects to a certain vpn, receive packets and sent packets.

I have tried modifying google's Toyvpn and was able to create and vpn interface and i can see that there are packets sent but i dont see received packets..
[image]
I observe that google's ToyVpn doesn't have username and only had server address , port and shared secret (i think is the password).

So now im trying to understand how does google require username and password to connect to the vpn i have created via android settings.Please give some links or idea how do they do it.